# JSf2 sending ajax requests to the server of individual input elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a dynamic set of input items that I create on the page load. I need to trigger an ajax request when each of these text boxes change its value. I need to get the changed value and the changed item's id.

```
<h:form> <ui:repeat value="#{aBean.inputItems}" var="content"> 
<h:inputText id="inputfield#{content.id}" value="#{content.value}" label="lbl" >
         <f:ajax execute="@form" event="valueChange" listener="#{aBean.testListener}" render="@this"/>
</h:inputText> 
</ui:repeat> 
</h:form>
```

my backing bean(aBean) has a method.

```
public void testListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){

}
```

1. is there any way of getting the value changed input field's new value inside the "testListener" method?
2. else is this need to be fulfilled using javascirpt?

any feedback related to this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Just get it straight from the parent `<h:inputText>` component which you in turn can obtain from [`AjaxBehaviorEvent#getComponent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/FacesEvent.html#getComponent%28%29).

   ```
   UIInput input = (UIInput) event.getComponent();
   String contentId = input.getId().substring("inputfield".length());
   Object contentValue = (Content) input.getValue();
   // ...
   ```
2. Obtain the whole `Content` object as current `<ui:repeat var>` value from the request attribute map which you in turn can obtain from [`ExternalContext#getRequestMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29).

   ```
   Map<String, Object> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
   Content content = (Content) requestMap.get("content");
   // ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you change the value inside the listener. It would be just:

```
this.property = newValue;
```

2) If you are doing it on the server, then no JavaScript is involved.